# Code Coverage for WCF source with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

Want to get code coverage for the WCF source against the unit test automation written.
Test project has a service reference to the WCF and adding "SymbolSearchPaths" in runsettings is not helping when executing the tests with VSTEST.Console.Exe

Any help appreciated.